# Merge two data-sets in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have two datasets in the below format & want to merge them into a single dataset based on City+Age+Gender. Thanks in advance

Dataset1:

```
        City    Age  Gender            Source         Count
0  California  15-24  Female  Amazon Prime Video       14629
1  California  15-24  Female             Fubo TV        3840
2  California  15-24  Female                Hulu       54067
3  California  15-24  Female             Netflix       11713
4  California  15-24  Female            Sling TV       10642
```

Dataset2:

```
         City    Age  Gender           Source     Feeds
0  California  15-24  Female             Blogs    150
1  California  15-24  Female        Customsite     57
2  California  15-24  Female       Discussions     28
3  California  15-24  Female  Facebook Comment    555
4  California  15-24  Female           Google+     19
```

Expected resulting dataset:

```
    City      Age   Gender            Source          Count
  California  15-24  Female  Amazon Prime Video       14629
  California  15-24  Female             Fubo TV        3840
  California  15-24  Female                Hulu       54067
  California  15-24  Female             Netflix       11713
  California  15-24  Female            Sling TV       10642
  California  15-24  Female             Blogs          150
  California  15-24  Female        Customsite           57
  California  15-24  Female       Discussions           28
  California  15-24  Female  Facebook Comment          555
  California  15-24  Female           Google+           19
```

Note : Feeds/Count signify the same meaning. So okay to have either of them as the column name in the merged dataset.

Comment: Sorry for the delay as I was on holidays. Checked it today & works just fine.. thanks

Comment: No problem, you are welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`pandas.concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with `rename` columns for align columns - need same columns in `both DataFrames`:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2.rename(columns={'Feeds':'Count'})], ignore_index=True)
print (df)
         City    Age  Gender              Source  Count
0  California  15-24  Female  Amazon Prime Video  14629
1  California  15-24  Female             Fubo TV   3840
2  California  15-24  Female                Hulu  54067
3  California  15-24  Female             Netflix  11713
4  California  15-24  Female            Sling TV  10642
5  California  15-24  Female               Blogs    150
6  California  15-24  Female          Customsite     57
7  California  15-24  Female         Discussions     28
8  California  15-24  Female    Facebook Comment    555
9  California  15-24  Female             Google+     19
```

Alternative with [`DataFrame.append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) - not pure [`python append`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html):

```
df = df1.append(df2.rename(columns={'Feeds':'Count'}), ignore_index=True)
print (df)
         City    Age  Gender              Source  Count
0  California  15-24  Female  Amazon Prime Video  14629
1  California  15-24  Female             Fubo TV   3840
2  California  15-24  Female                Hulu  54067
3  California  15-24  Female             Netflix  11713
4  California  15-24  Female            Sling TV  10642
5  California  15-24  Female               Blogs    150
6  California  15-24  Female          Customsite     57
7  California  15-24  Female         Discussions     28
8  California  15-24  Female    Facebook Comment    555
9  California  15-24  Female             Google+     19
```